# php how to echo string in output and format numbers

Tags: php, string, output, echo

Hi i am trying to echo and output where the height is correctly displayed as 5ft 8ins however i am unaware how to do this.
I am new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

The end result should look like:
Height in feet and inches: 5ft 8ins

```
$heightMeters = 1.75;
$heightInches = $heightMeters * 100 /2.54;
$heightFeet = $heightInches / 12;
echo 'Height in Feet and inches: '.$heightFeet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (explanation in code comments):

```
// given height in meters
$heightMeters = 1.75;

// convert the given height into inches
$heightInches = $heightMeters * 100 /2.54;

// feet = integer quotient of inches divided by 12
$heightFeet = floor($heightInches / 12);

// balance inches after $heightfeet
// so if 68 inches, balance would be remainder of 68 divided by 12 = 4
$balanceInches = floor($heightInches % 12);

// prepare display string for the height
$heightStr = 'Height in Feet and inches: ';
// If feet is greater than zero then add it to string
$heightStr .= ($heightFeet > 0 ? $heightFeet . 'ft ' : '');
// If balance inches is greater than zero then add it to string
$heightStr .= ($balanceInches > 0 ? $balanceInches . 'ins' : '');

// Display the string
echo $heightStr;
```

Comment: yes thank this worked. only thing that needed changing was adding ' ' between the ft and $balanceInches.

Comment: @NoviceProg14 happy to help :)